# How to attach sun shade to wood siding with concrete underneath?

Tags: concrete, anchor

I would like to install a sunshade on our apartment patio where one side for the attachments is a concrete wall.  The other side for the attachments is a wall that has wood siding with (I think) concrete behind it.  I would like to be able to use Stainless Steel hardware too so that it will not rust.

Here is the sunshade I am interested in:
[https://www.amazon.com/Canopy-Rectangle-Outdoor-Facility-Activities/dp/B0CBCJWH6N/ref=sr_1_7?th=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0CBCJWH6N)

Here is a stainless steel hardware kit that is recommended for it, but I am not sure if I can use it as it has plates with four mounting holes in each of them (might be tough to drill four holes in concrete, spaced close to each other, and still have them align with the holes):
[https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07H969LH3/ref=emc_b_5_t?th=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07H969LH3)

The other difficulty is that the apartment is a rental, so I don't want to drill huge wide holes in the wood siding to get to the concrete (which I suppose I would have to do if I use anchors for concrete).  But, if I need to, I guess it would be OK.

I have drilled holes in concrete before and used anchors (made of some kind of lead like material?).  Do you recommend anchors for concrete here?  Or do they have some kind of screw in eyelet for concrete that is sold?

Also, preferably, I would like to use stainless steel mounting hardware if possible.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sun shades not anchored correctly do not last in wind.  Wood sliding is usually not strong enough.  As a rental get written permission before doing anything.

Comment: Solid concrete, or concrete block?